# IPhone stuck on apple logo and I'm jailbroken

Tags: iphone, battery, jailbreak, restore, ios

So I wanted to remove my jailbreak so I pressed "Erase all contents and settings". This led to my phone being stuck so I plugged it in my comp and put it in DFU mode. My phone was really low on battery so I didnt notice so now whenever I put it in DFU mode, it will say there's no battery, and when it turns on it's back on the apple logo and I dont think it charges when it is at the apple logo... What do I do? If I leave it charging, it will just turn back on to the apple logo and not charge..

Comment: The iPhone charges as long as you have a cable connected. It's easier to charge it if it's in Recovery Mode, though, since it uses a lot less power. Do you know how to get it into Recovery Mode? And another thing while you're in Recovery Mode, you can restore the device using iTunes. Let me know if this works for you. If it does, I'll convert my comment to a real answer.

Comment: I really dont think it charges while on the apple logo. I left it for 15 minutes and when I tried to enter DFU, it said I had no battery and it went straight back to the apple logo

Comment: How do you enter recovery mode? Also my device is not showing up on iTunes..

Comment: At this point, your iPhone won't show up in iTunes unless it's in Recovery Mode. Open up iTunes; while the iPhone is off, hold the Home button down; while you're holding the button down, plug the iPhone into your computer and keep holding down the button. It should immediately enter Recovery Mode and you can let go of the button (this is the easiest method, but requires you have a computer, iTunes, and a USB cable).

Comment: I cant do this since I can't force my phone to be off. Its only off when its no battery. After that it goes back to apple logo and I cant close it unless I do a DFU or a reboot (the one with holding home and top button)

Comment: Well I got something to work... I got the recovery mode step and restrored it. It said waiting for iphone but nothing happened after thazt

Comment: May I ask one more question? I backed up before doing all this but when I try restoring it to the backup, it doesn't appear on itunes? Do you know how to get that backup?

Comment: It's possible it was backed up to iCloud, but you're probably better off asking a new question.

Comment: If you'd be so kind as to mark my answer as correct, I'd appreciate it. Thanks! And welcome to AskDifferent!

Answer (score 1):

iOS devices charge as long as you have a USB cable connected. But at the Apple logo, it's using a lot of power and might take hours to charge to just a few percent.

Regardless, at this point, your iPhone won't show up in iTunes unless it's in [Recovery Mode](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Recovery_Mode). You should [put your device into Recovery Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201263) and [restore iOS with iTunes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252).